# How can I reload a VIM plugin after VIM was started?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am modifying an installed VIM plugin and in another Terminal tab I am testing the results.
Each time I want to test the changes I have to restart VIM.

Is there any faster way to do this process? How can I reload a VIM plugin after VIM was started?

The plugin is installed via [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle)

I have tried to run `:so %` that is supposed to [reload the `.vimrc` file](https://superuser.com/a/132030) but I still cannot see my changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there weren't an *inclusion guard* (`if ! exists('g:loaded_pluginname') ...`), you could simply `:runtime! plugin/pluginname.vim` (or `:source %` if it's currently opened) and all plugin definitions would be re-read.

But as most plugins (correctly) use such a guard, you need to `:unlet` that variable first:

```
:unlet g:loaded_pluginname | runtime! plugin/pluginname.vim
```

My [ReloadScript plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1904) can do this with one command if the guard name adheres to the canonical naming, and [the scriptease plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4394) has such a command, too.

**Edit:** Some plugins use differently named guard variables, or other ways that prevent reloading. The plugins from mattn (like *emmet.vim*) are quite elaborate; maybe there's some special mechanism; I don't use that plugin. You could ask the author for advice, though.

Comment: What's the plugin name, and which guard variable does it use?

Comment: It's the first time when I edit a VIM plugin. Its name is [emmet-vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim).

Comment: Ah, its guard name is non-standard; you need to explicitly `:unlet g:loaded_emmet_vim`.

Comment: Can you explain me what you mean when saying *you need to explicitly `:unlet g:loaded_emmet_vim`*?

Comment: My ReloadScript plugin expects a `g:loaded_emmet` name, so it cannot automatically reload the plugin (as you've noticed). That's why the `:unlet` is required.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46372/discussion-between-ionic-bizu-and-ingo-karkat)